# regex lazy matching + grouping

Tags: regex

I am having trouble with regex lazy matching. It's hard to explain without an example:

My regex: `A\d*?(88)?\d*?B`

---

Example 1: `A12388456B`

What I want: matches string, group 1 matches the "88"

What happens: matches string, but group 1 is not matched.

---

Example 2: `A123B`

What I want: matches string, group 1 not matched.

What happens: works correctly

---

Basically I want group 1 to match the "88" if it appears, but I want to also match any pattern `A\d+B`.

This seems like it should be simple, but I am having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this regex in Javascript:

```
 'A12388456B'.match(/A(?:\d*?(88))?\d*?B/);
 > ["A12388456B", "88"]  // Matches string and 88.

 'A123B'.match(/A(?:\d*?(88))?\d*?B/);
 > ["A123B", undefined]  // Matches string but nothing else.
```

In the first example, group 1 captures 88.

Comment: You can make it non capturing group with `(?:)` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your first group that you want matched is not marked as a group.

You'd want:

<strike>(A\d*)?(88)?\d*?B</strike>

Then you have two subgroups, and main match.

Comment: I do not want the A to be optional. This also doesn't seem to work, I get group 1 = "A12388456", group 2 unmatched for example #1

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I misunderstood the second scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex `A(?=\d*(88))\d*B` and group 1 will contain `88` if match found.